# Adding pixel values of images in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

Long story short, I'm implementing an algorithm I prototyped in Matlab. I need to add the RGB values of two images pixel by pixel. However, it seems that none of the blending filters in Core Image can do this. I know it's not hard to implement a custom filter, but is there any built in method for adding two images?

Comment: Can you provide us the result of your matlab, i.e., source image and combined image. It will help us understand how you are expecting the images to be added.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add The RGB values, go for [CIAdditionCompositing](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIAdditionCompositing) filter. 
This filter add the RGB vaues of two images (which will make image brighter)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.deepskycolors.com/archivo/2010/04/21/formulas-for-Photoshop-blending-modes.html), CILinearDodgeBlendMode produce the literal addition of pixel values. CIAdditionCompositing seems to do something [special](http://keithp.com/~keithp/porterduff/p253-porter.pdf).

I'm not 100% sure about these, but so far CILinearDodgeBlendMode produces the best result I want.